# What did I do CORRECTLY?-comparing index from string using .at(), error messages

Tags: c++, string, indexing

The program I am writing is supposed to accept a social security number in the format ddd-dd-dddd.

My class textbook says that the format to index a specific character from a string is to use variable.at(index)

I used that format unsuccessfully. This is what DIDN'T work:

```
if ("-" == social.at(2) && "-" == social.at(5)){
```

It returns "Invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string') and 'std::basic_string::value_type' (aka 'char'))"

After researching previously-asked questions on here, [I tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18794865/18207002) on a whim, which works:

```
      if ("-" == string(1, social[2]) && "-" == string(1, social[5])) {
```

However, I don't know what the difference between the two is. I am specifically confused by:

```
string(1,
```

Why is there a 1? Also, why did this work when the syntax I got from my textbook didn't? What method is this? Any help and resources are appreciated!

Comment: The original should use single quotes:  `'-' == social.at(2)`.  Single quotes is a `char`, double quotes is a c string.

Comment: As for `string(1, ...`, you've used a particular `string` constructor used to repeat a single character. It repeats the character in the 2nd parameter as many times as the first parameter. You converted a character to a std::string, then compared to a c string.

Comment: A [String Literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in this case.